# Mock server for https connection

Tags: ssl, server, ssl-certificate

I have learnt about SSL and SSL certificates used on client and server side. I pretty much understand how things work and have generated server and client certificates and keys. I have studied how can I use my own CA with `https` in Android.

I want to setup a server where I can put the server certificate and then access it from my android device to make an emulation of what I have learnt so far.

Is there any server available where I just need to put `cert` and `key` and it will start working? I have gone through `wamp` and `apache` configuration stuff but unfortunately I am unable to make it work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using OpenSSL it includes a very simple server named `s_server` which is very useful for this kind of experimentation. Here's an example that might get you started

```
$ openssl s_server -key test.key -cert test.crt -accept 8443 -WWW
```

This will serve up files in the current working directory from https://localhost:8443/

The manpage for s_server should give you all the info you need. I think you'll want the `-CApath` or `-CAfile` options if you're also experimenting with client certs.

Comment: Thanks @JustATrick. Let me try it.